# Promise all finishing early when dynamically adding to promises array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise

This code works as expected:

```
services.map(async svc => {
  promises.push(new Promise(async (resolve) => {
    html += `<h2>${svc}</h2>`;

    let journeyDetails = await admin.database().ref(`data`).once('value');

    resolve();
  }));
});

await Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
  return res.send(html);
})
```

Why does the code below not work? In my eyes it's the same, but the execution order is now incorrect.

```
Promise.all([
  services.map(async svc => {
    new Promise(async (resolve) => {
      html += `<h2>${svc}</h2>`;

      let journeyDetails = await admin.database().ref(`data`).once('value');

      resolve();
    })
  })
]).then(() => {
  // done - called before finished in this version
}).catch(() => {
  // err
});
```

Comment: You're not returning the promise in the second version.

Comment: @Phix Just added return and it's still not waiting

Comment: This looks like a new twist on the [explicit promise antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the primary reason that your code doesn't work is that you are passing an array of arrays (`[services.map(...)]`) to `Promise.all`, not an array of promises.

However, the code is unnecessarily complex. There is no need to create a promise inside an `async` function, `async` functions always return a promise. It should just be:

```
Promise.all( // <- note the removed [...]
  services.map(async svc => {
    html += `<h2>${svc}</h2>`;
    let journeyDetails = await admin.database().ref(`data`).once('value');
    // more code here
  })
)
```

Comment: Thanks Felix. For the question I removed a bit of non-asynchronous code after the async database function which was important. How would I handle that now in your example as wouldn't this stop that from executing?

Comment: You can put whatever you want after the `await`.